# Enabling hstore when deploying with rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-ec2, hstore, rubber

I'm deploying a Rails app that uses PostgreSQL and HSTORE.

To deploy it, I'm ussing [rubber](http://github.com/rubber/rubber).

Everything works, except for HSTORE not being properly enabled. When the migration that contains `execute("CREATE EXTENSION hstore")` runs, I get the following errors:

```
** [out :: production.---] 
** [out :: production.---] -- execute("CREATE EXTENSION hstore")
** [out :: production.---] 
** [out :: production.---] rake aborted!
** [out :: production.---] An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
** [out :: production.---] 
** [out :: production.---] PG::Error: ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "hstore"
** [out :: production.---] HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

The script that creates the postgres instance has this code:

```
create_user_cmd = "CREATE USER #{env.db_user} WITH NOSUPERUSER CREATEDB NOCREATEROLE"
```

so I think the problem might be related to the `NOSUPERUSER` attribute being set here.

Is there any way to enable hstore using rubber while keeping most of the generated files unchanged?

Comment: Have you tried the gem `activerecord-postgres-hstore`? It installs hstore's functionality by migration.

Comment: The problem lies in the permissions when running the migration. I have the gem installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that rubber creates the DB user as `NOSUPERUSER`. My workaround is to create tasks that run before and after capistrano's `deploy:migrate` that will change the user to `SUPERUSER` and back.

Here's the code:

```
namespace :rubber do

  namespace :project do

    before "deploy:migrate", "rubber:project:add_pg_superuser_and_enable_hstore"
    after "deploy:migrate", "rubber:project:remove_pg_superuser"

    task :add_pg_superuser_and_enable_hstore,
         :roles => [:postgresql_master, :postgresql_slave] do
      alter_user_cmd = "ALTER USER #{rubber_env.db_user} SUPERUSER"
      create_hstore_cmd = "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;"
      rubber.sudo_script "add_superuser_create_hstore", <<-ENDSCRIPT
        sudo -i -u postgres psql -c "#{alter_user_cmd}"
        sudo -i -u postgres psql -c "#{create_hstore_cmd}"
      ENDSCRIPT
    end

    task :remove_pg_superuser, :roles => [:postgresql_master,
                                          :postgresql_slave] do
      alter_user_cmd = "ALTER USER #{rubber_env.db_user} NOSUPERUSER"
      rubber.sudo_script "add_superuser_create_hstore", <<-ENDSCRIPT
        sudo -i -u postgres psql -c "#{alter_user_cmd}"
      ENDSCRIPT
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I added it to the bottom of my config/deploy.rb and I was back up and running. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think we should be recommending people enable superuser as general purpose answer. Rubber generates files that you are free to modify. You should just modify the generated deploy-postgresql.rb to create the extension along with the other privileged SQL being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to not have a postgres superuser involved when deploying but create a template (or use the default one) and install the extension on the template. Then when you create a database it will have the extension installed.

Good answers [here](http://clarkdave.net/2012/09/postgresql-error-type-hstore-does-not-exist/) and [here](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore/issues/99).